# Linux: Search through sub-folders recursively for a file that contains a string and move it to another file

Tags: grep

So far, I have this command on my terminal and it doesn't do anything.
Essentially it's to look for any file that contains the word bango and move it to another directory.

```
grep -r ".*bango.*" /Users/user/Desktop/drums | xargs mv /Users/user/Desktop/bango
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep has a function to list the filename only you should use that to list the name of the files.

Also xargs can build commands with positional arguments.

Try to use

`grep -rlE ".*bango.*" /Users/user/Desktop/drums | xargs -I @ mv @ /Users/user/Desktop/bango`

The option -E allows to use regular expressions.

However, a regular expression is not needed, you can activate a fast grep algorithm for fixed strings:

`grep -rlF "bango" /Users/user/Desktop/drums | xargs -I @ mv @ /Users/user/Desktop/bango`

Comment: That is helpful, but it doesn't work. I ensured that the string sequence was in the sub-folders as well. Please help.

Comment: `.bango.` means `bango` with at least one char either side while the OP wanted `.*bango.*` which means **zero** or more characters either side which is equivalent to just `bango`.

Comment: oh okay, that's good to know thank you. However does the command work? It does not seem to be doing anything for me. BTW when I say linux, I'm using the Mac OS terminal just in case that makes a difference.

Comment: In order to use a regular expression, you must indicate grep to do just that. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: if grep -rlF "bango" /Users/user/Desktop/drums | xargs -I @ mv @ /Users/user/Desktop/bango is the edited answer, it still does not work unfortunately. I tried with several different string sequence and it doesn't seem to work. I'm not getting an error though

Comment: It does make a difference that you're using Mac OS, because find and xargs are different there. If you use [brew](https://brew.sh/), try:

brew install findutils --with-default-names

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that there is a difference. I tried the same command on linux mint and it doesn't seem to do anything either. I looked up the the Mac version of xargs and it seems they use the place holder {} instead of @. I don't really know the major difference. Would it be possible for me to acquire the command for Mac from somewhere, I been searching all over google. I was about to just do everything manually until I figured that I might have to resort other set of data if the one I have right now is not enough. Unfortunately, the bottom line is the command do not work I thin

Comment: Any help on this?